# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I couldn't understand why...here is the GitHub repository: https://github.com/Dronrom/React-test

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: you are passing arr as null to renderItems function,

Comment: Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, data, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That’s because you initialized peopleList as null in your component. So map works only on arrays so you need to check peopleList whether its really an array before doing map on it so

Change

```
   renderItems(arr) {
    return arr.map(({id, name}) => {
        return (
            <li className="list-group-item"
                key={id}
                onClick={() => this.props.onItemSelected(id)}>
                 {name}
            </li>
        );
    });
}
```

To

```
  renderItems(arr) {
      if(arr){
            return arr.map(({id, name}) => {
                 return (
                     <li className="list-group-item"
                key={id}
                onClick={() => this.props.onItemSelected(id)}>
                        {name}
                    </li>
                );
            });
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue may be that react renders once before componentDidMount(). This is an issue because your calling map on arr which is null.  const { peopleList } = this.state; you set people list to your current state which you set as default to be null, state = {peopleList: null}; then you later call this.renderItems(peopleList); which people list is still null at this moment so you are getting the Cannot read property 'map' of null error.
I belive something like componentWillMount is what you need instead. I recommend looking at this post which has a similar issue of react life cycle methods. [React render() is being called before componentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337165/react-render-is-being-called-before-componentdidmount)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is very simple: the type of the input isn't `array` type, it might be `null` or `undefined`. so that it doesn't have `.map` function.

How to fix:

- Make sure your input must be `array` type before call `renderItems()`.

```js
    render(){
        const { peopleList } = this.state;


        const items = (peopleList && peopleList.length) ? this.renderItems(peopleList) : null;

        return(
            <ul className="item-list list-group">
                {items}
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

Or:

- Make sure your input must be `array` type before do mapping:

```js
       renderItems(arr) {
          return !arr ? null : arr.map(({id, name}) => {
            return (
                 <li className="list-group-item"
                     key={id}
                     onClick={() => this.props.onItemSelected(id)}>
                      {name}
                 </li>
             );
           });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response)))

Answer (score 0):

```
{product.size?.map(c=>(

                <FilterSizeOption key={c}>{c}</FilterSizeOption>
                ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the return statement with a if statement worked for me

So changed

```
return (
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    {countries.map((country, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span key={`${country.name.common}${i}`}>
            {country.name.common}
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

to this

```
  if (countries) {
return (
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    {countries.map((country, i) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span key={`${country.name.common}${i}`}>
            {country.name.common}
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

}