# Console log returns 3 values when only one object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, import

I'm trying to conditionally import a pdf file which I call `const techSheet` below, but for some reason when I `console.log(wine.Code)` it returns 3 things: undefined, correct result, correct result.

(result of console.log):

```
onewine.js:64 Code: undefined
onewine.js:64 Code: FGA-CHA17
onewine.js:64 Code: FGA-CHA17
```

Everything looks fine in state, there's only one object in this.state.wine so I can't figure out why, #1 It's returning 3 values #2 why the first one is undefined.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import API from "../utils/API";
import { Grid} from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


class OneWine extends Component {
  state = {
    wine: {}
  };

 componentDidMount() {

    API.getWine(this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(res => this.setState({ wine: res.data }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

render() {
    const { wine } = this.state;
    const techSheet = require(`../TechSheets/Tech_${wine.Code}.pdf`);
    console.log("Code:", wine.Code)


    return (

     <a href = {techSheet} target = "_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
          <Button basic color="brown" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Tech Sheet
          </Button>
     </a>

    );
  }
}

export default OneWine;
```

I don't have any other console.logs or anything. Why is this coming up as undefined for the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Generally with cases like these the log statement gets called more than once. 
This would be supported in your case by the fact that `Render()` actually gets called before `ComponentDidMount()` (see: http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/).

Render then gets called twice after ComponentDidMount (and other state updates), having the right solution after the ComponentDidMount call.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how react calls the render method.

The render method is run before componentDidMount.

refer to this answer:
[React render() is being called before componentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343644/10134980)

Answer (score 0):

Because render is called before componentDidMount() 1 time, where the state is still `{wine: {}}`.

[image: React lifecycle]