# TypeError: Cannot read property 'rocket_name' of undefined -- Even though it is defined

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router

I'm using the `SpaceX` API to build a personal project. I'm using React Router to dynamically load components, rather than refreshing the whole website.

Here is my `LaunchDetails` component where I'm trying to output some data:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class LaunchDetail extends Component {
  state = {
    launch: []
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/${this.props.match.params.flight_number}`)
      const data = await res.json()
      this.setState({
        launch: data,
        rocket: data.rocket
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { launch, rocket } = this.state

    console.log(rocket)

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>{launch.mission_name}</h1>
          <p>SpaceX Flight Number: {launch.flight_number}</p>
          <p>Launched: {launch.launch_year}</p>
          <p>Rocket: {rocket.rocket_name}, {rocket.rocket_type}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LaunchDetail
```

Data one level deep like `launch.mission_name` is displaying correctly... However, when I try and go down another level, say, `rocket.rocket_name (eg: launch.rocket.rocket_name)`, it throws the above error.

What is strange is that this works in another component, but that is using a different end point (all the data) and I'm mapping through it. Not sure if the way I'm calling the data in this component is to blame or not...

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

**EDIT: I've updated the code to be simpler after receiving some comments, error still persists:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class LaunchDetail extends Component {
  state = {
    launch: []
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/${this.props.match.params.flight_number}`)
      const data = await res.json()
      this.setState({
        launch: data
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { launch } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>{launch.mission_name}</h1>
          <p>SpaceX Flight Number: {launch.flight_number}</p>
          <p>Launched: {launch.launch_year}</p>
          <p>Rocket: {launch.rocket.rocket_name}, {launch.rocket_type}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LaunchDetail
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not caused by "3 level deep" properties, but more so this in your render: `rocket.rocket_name`. The rocket isn't initially defined in state, so `this.state.rocket` will be undefined, and that access subproperties of it will give the error you're geting. You fetch the data in `componentDidMount`, but that lifecycle method is called AFTER the first render. So if you should have a loading state for the rendering (for when data is being fetched) and preferably default values for the state

Comment: Try initializing `rocket` in your initial `state = {
    launch: []
  }`

Comment: Ok, so I added `rocket` to state, still same error. I've now removed it so that it now references `launch.rocket.rocket_name` and still the error persists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343644/10377254) you can find that the react lifecycle methods go in the following order.

*componentWillMount* --> *render* --> *componentDidMount*

You have initialized state with

```js
state = {
  launch: []
}
```

So on the first render, `state.rocket` will be undefined.

To fix this, either initialise state.rocket or change `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount`
With the former being prefered.

Note `componentWillMount` is deprecated in version 17.

---

After OP's edit. You are still initializing launch to []

On the first render `launch.rocket` will be undefined. Therefore `launch.rocket.rocket_name` will throw an error.

Either initialise `launch` to have a `rocket` field. Or do something like

`(launch.rocket || {}).rocket_name`, or something else to check that `rocket` is defined before accessing `rocket_name`.

Comment: Thank you, this is my code:

`launch: { rocket: [] }`

Comment: Hopefully you see this, how come I need to initialise state for `rocket` and any other data in this component and not in a different component where I'm calling all the data? I hope that makes sense...

Comment: The only reason you will need to initialise state for rocket in this component is for the first render. As you are assuming there will always be a `launch` object with a `rocket` prop that has the `rocket_name` field.

Comment: Personally I would go for not initialising rocket in this component, and using something like `(launch.rocket || {}).rocket_name` in my render. This way, if `rocket` is undefined, accessing `rocket_name` will not throw an error and it will just render nothing. After `rocket` is initialized via `componentDidMount` it will render the new `rocket_name`